# AngularJS custom validation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have three inputs, and each of them needs a custom validation.
So I've made a directive like this to validate them:

```
function CardValidator(ValidatorService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            $element.on('keyup', function(e) {
                var isValid = ValidatorService.checkValidity(e.target.value);
                ngModel.$setValidity($attrs.ngModel, isValid);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <form method="post" autocomplete="off" name="formCard" novalidate>
        <div class="row field">
            <i class="icon icon-cpf"></i>
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.card.number" name="card" card-validator mask="9999  9999  9999  9999" required>
            <label>cartão</label>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <div class="row field field-medium left">
                <i class="icon icon-cpf"></i>
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.card.expireDate" card-valid-thru-validator mask="99/99" required>
                <label>validade MM/AA</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row field field-medium field-last right">
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.card.cvv" card-security-code-validator required>
                <label>CVV</label>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </form>
```

Here's the HTML of the  after all three fields are valid:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" name="formCard" novalidate="" class="ng-dirty ng-valid-vm.card.number ng-valid-vm.card.expire-date ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-valid-vm.card.cvv">
```

The inputs are working, AngularJS is putting `ng-valid` and `ng-invalid` where it should. But the `form` as a whole is not working. When I call `form.$valid` it always returns true, even when the 3 input fields are with `ng-valid`.

Comment: Suggest you provide a demo that replicates issue. Numerous reasons this could happen such as child scope issues

Comment: I edited the post with the HTML

Comment: The `input` elements have no name. I wonder why you don't use [validators](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators).

Comment: Angular 1.2.0, @zeroflagL and I need specific validation

Comment: You can use `$parsers` then. Listening (only) to `keyup` is not the best of ideas. Your approach works, though. The last sentence of the question is confusing: If all inputs are valid, then of course the form is valid, too. It should be `formCard.$valid` btw.

Comment: $scope.$watch is better than keyup? Why? @zeroflagL

Comment: Where does `$scope.$watch` suddenly come from?